# Can I use Sente with Jetty 6?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have seen a Clojurescript websockets framework called Sente:

https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente

However, my server is Jetty 6, and looking at the github page it does not mention Jetty as a supported server. Is there any way to get Sente working with Jetty 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty is currently not supported. You may be able to get it to work, but it will require some development and investigation. See

https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente/issues/102